# Import java variables into excel?

Tags: java, excel

I was wondering if there is a way that I can import variables from my Java code directly into an excel cells. For example like one variable in one defined cell. Also the data is just variables in the code not in a data base. Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Matt

Comment: So you want to convert classes' fields to excel sheets?
You might want to read this first if you want to get some answers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show variable names and values at runtime try something like:

```
public static void exportObjectToExcel(final Object obj) {
    try {
        for (final Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                if (!field.isAccessible()) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                }
                Object value = field.get(obj);
                System.out.println("variable: \"" + field.getName() + "\", value: \"" + value + '"');
                //TODO Excel code here (e.g. Apache POI or JXL)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this maybe be what I'm looking for, with JXL can I write one variable into a target cell in excel?

Answer (score 0):

[Obba](http://www.obba.info) allows to access Java objects (members, methods, etc.) from within an Excel cell (in Excel).

(rem: I am a developer of this tool).